# TypeError Yii2 Framework

Tags: php, yii2

yii\base\View::{closure}(): Argument #2 ($model) must be of type Libro, app\models\Libro given

in C:\xampp\htdocs\biblioteca\views\libro\index.php

```
'filterModel' => $searchModel,
'columns' => [
    ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],

    'id',
    'titulo',
    'imagen',
    [
        'class' => ActionColumn::className(),
     *   'urlCreator' => function ($action, Libro $model, $key, $index, $column) {*
            return Url::toRoute([$action, 'id' => $model->id]);
         }
    ],
],
```

]); ?>

Comment: Error message says "must be of type Libro, app\models\Libro given". So, I guess you are in "app\models" namespace, so use `\Libro $model` or `use Libro;` after your `namespace` statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your closure from:

```
'urlCreator' => function ($action, Libro $model, $key, $index, $column) {*
    return Url::toRoute([$action, 'id' => $model->id]);
}
```

Into:

```
'urlCreator' => function ($action, \app\models\Libro $model, $key, $index, $column) {*
    return Url::toRoute([$action, 'id' => $model->id]);
}
```

> In other words, use right class as type (`\app\models\Libro` instead of `Libro`).

Answer (score 0):

Include below line at the beginning of the script along with other use statements:

```
use app\models\Libro;
```